# Can't return data from table - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The below query is only returning one result, even though there are multiple entries in the table with user_is 2. I m not sure what I m doing wrong.

```
function get_payments($user_id) 
{
$sql = "SELECT txn_id, payer_email FROM orders WHERE user_id = ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $user_id);

//echo $this->db->last_query();

if($query->num_rows() != 0) {
  foreach($query->result() as $payment)
  {
    $data[] = $payment;
    return $data;
  }
}else{
    return false;
}

}
```

This is what $this->db->last_query(); returns. `SELECT txn_id, payer_email FROM orders WHERE user_id = '2'`

Controller:

```
$profile_data['user_payments'] = $this->profile_model->get_payments($user_id);
```

View:

```
<?php 
//var_dump($user_payments);
  foreach($user_payments as $payment)
  {
    echo '<p>';
    echo $payment->txn_id;
    echo $payment->payer_email;
    echo '</p>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a slight mistake here

```
foreach($query->result() as $payment)
  {
    $data[] = $payment;
    return $data; // this line returns the data and it stops execution in first loop itself
  }
```

it should be like

```
if($query->num_rows() != 0) {
    foreach($query->result() as $payment)
      {
        $data[] = $payment;
      }
  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php 
function get_payments($user_id){
    $this->db->select('txn_id, payer_email')
        ->from('orders')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $qry = $this->db->get();
    $res = $qry->result();
    if($res){
        return $res;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should return `$data` from model after foreach loop completes.

```
if($query->num_rows() != 0) {
    foreach($query->result() as $payment)
    {
      $data[] = $payment;
    }
   return $data;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple CI way:

```
...
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $user_id);
return $query->result_array();
```

No looping needed, nothing.

And I see you're using the object form, in that case do this:

```
return $query->result();
```

Then just loop it in your view like you're already doing.

---

So this is the whole model method:

```
function get_payments($user_id) {
  $sql = "SELECT txn_id, payer_email FROM orders WHERE user_id = ?";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql, $user_id);
  return $query->result();
}
```

See the relevant docs here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

---

And using Active Records (the most "natural" to CI):

```
function get_payments($user_id) {
    return $this->db
        ->select('txn_id, payer_email')
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->get('orders')
        ->result();
}
```

Comment: `It returns false in case of no rows`. not really, it generates `empty array` instead.

Comment: because `array() != false` maybe I'm too harsh but this line `It returns false in case of no rows` is misleading and doesn't suit to a reputed member like you. sorry though ;)